# How Javascript asyc and await working in this particular code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have implemented an async function which creates an XHR object inside a Promise, requests a data from the server and fulfills the Promise with the response received from the server

```
async function playWordsAudio(id, type, check=false){
    
    let file_namePromise = new Promise(function (onSuccess, onFailure){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                if(this.responseText !== "No Data"){
                    file_name = this.responseText;
                    if(check == false){
                        audio = new Audio('assets/uploads/wav/' + file_name);
                        audio.play();
                    }else{
                        onSuccess(file_name);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(check){
                        onSuccess('Not Found');
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "scripts/get_word_audio.php?id=" + id + "&type=" + type, true);
        xhttp.send();   
    });

    let resultant = await file_namePromise;

    if(check){
        return resultant;
    }
}
```

Later I have defined another function which calls the async function shown above

```
function modify_object(id, type, obj){
    result = playWordsAudio(id, type, true);
    result.then(function(value){
        if(value == "Not Found"){
            obj.classList.remove('fa-play');
        }
    }); 
}
```

Later in the implementation I also call the modify_object function and pass it an object for modification as described in the function.

```
modify_object(id, type, plays[i]);
```

In the async function I have created a Promise, on success I pass it the file_name received from the XHR response or else I pass it 'Not Found'.

Here I am confused on how the await part works inside the asyc function.
It returns the resultant to the caller of the async function which is

```
result = playWordsAudio(id, type, true);
```

If so, what does the onSuccess method in the Promise do

```
let file_namePromise = new Promise(function (onSuccess, onFailure){
/*
    Some Codes
*/

onSuccess(file_name);

/*
    Some more code
*/

onSuccess('Not Found);

/*
    Rest of the Code
*/
}
```

As I have checked by commenting out the return statement after the await statement

```
if(check){
//    return resultant;
}
```

The Promise is not fulfilled.

How does each part of the implementation work as described above?

Comment: Your code is a bit weird, but you should at least 1) handle failure conditions and 2) _always_ call either `onSuccess` or `onFailure`, sometimes you do neither. I would also suggest to remove more stuff from your question to make it simpler.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: @Evert , I am not sure what is weird in the code, I would be glad if you point out the problems. I haven't handled the failure condition as I am not sure what is going on with the Promise stuffs.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @GuerricP I am kinda stuck in the old days of using XHR. Next time I would consider using fetch. Thanks.

Comment: @JoyRamSenGupta, what's weird about it, and what I would change I exactly pointed out in my comment.